# why is there a lag in executing this javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to run a - accept our terms pop up box - that must be accepted before the page can be seen. I think I found answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588167/how-do-i-make-a-popup-appear-immediately-before-the-rest-of-the-page-loads

But I am at a loss to what I was doing wrong, and why my method had a time lag.

I uploaded http://jsfiddle.net/ZqVuj/2/ as example - If you click run you can see the lorem pops up for a moment then black.  Why does the modal not work before the rest of the page loads?

Someone built the page Im on off the code from this page:  http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

I took out the fade-ins, and changed $(document).ready(function() to $(function()

Yet the text still loads for a moment before the modal kicks in.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `$(function()` which is the same as `$(document).ready(function()`. What you'd want to do is put it right at the start of the body. http://jsfiddle.net/ZqVuj/3/

Comment: Both of the approaches you tried wait for the DOM to load, so the text shows up first.

Comment: thanks - I see I learnt it a bit wrong.  I thought just take out ready and off you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$(function() {...})`, use `(function() { ... })();` and put it right at the top of the `<body>`. That way, it will run instantly before the page content is shown.

Bear in mind, though, that anyone with basic knowledge of their browser can just remove the popup and reveal the content. You should use a more reliable method for securing your content.

Comment: yeah great - thanks for example.  I would have gone crazy without the extra brackets () at end.

Comment: @Jon The extra _parenthesis_ at the end run the anonymous function that was defined. Clarifying why they are absolutely necessary :)